# What's different between Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C in Unix command line?

Tags: command-line, unix

I'm using Mac OS X Terminal. And I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop some programs. But I realized that I don't know what they're exactly doing. What are they and what's the difference between them?

> This question was a **[Super User Question of the Week](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2302/super-user-questions-of-the-week-10)**.
>   Read the March 13, 2011 **[blog entry](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/13/signalling-for-your-processs-attention/)** for more details or **[submit your own](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week?sort=newest)** Question of the Week.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is used for **suspending** a process by sending it the signal `SIGTSTP`, which cannot be intercepted by the program. While <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used to **kill** a process with the signal `SIGINT`, and can be intercepted by a program so it can clean its self up before exiting, or not exit at all.

If you suspend a process, this will show up in the shell to tell you it has been suspended:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 yes
```

However, if you kill one, you won't see any confirmation other than being dropped back to a shell prompt. When you suspend a process, you can do fancy things with it, too. For instance, running this:

```
fg
```

With a program suspended will bring it back to the foreground.

And running the command

```
bg
```

With a program suspended will allow it to run in the background (the program's output will still go to the TTY, though).

If you want to kill a suspended program, you don't have to bring it back with `fg` first, you can simply do the command:

```
kill %1
```

If you have multiple suspended commands, running

```
jobs
```

will list them, like this:

```
[1]-  Stopped                 pianobar
[2]+  Stopped                 yes
```

Using `%#`, where `#` is the job number (the one in square brackets from the `jobs` output) with `bg`, `fg`, or `kill`, can be used to do the action on that job.

Comment: You can change which keys do which job by using the `stty` command. For example `stty susp ^Z`  or `stty intr ^C`.

Comment: Actually, it sends SIGTSTP, which can be intercepted.

Comment: Cool! So if a program is refusing to die with Ctrl+C how do you force kill it?

Comment: @adityamenon Find the executable name, for example `amarok` and run `killall amarok`, or run `ps aux` and find the process id next to the executable name and run `kill {process id}`.

Answer (score 25):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSTOP
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTSTP
- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_(POSIX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29)

Ctrl+Z suspends the process with SIGTSTP, you can resume it later.  Ctrl+C kills the process with SIGINT, which terminates the process unless it is handled/ignored by the target, so you can't resume it.  There's also a SIGSTOP which can be sent by `kill()` and which the process can't intercept.  SIGCONT is the counterpart to both SIGSTOP and SIGTSTP that un-suspends the process.

Comment: No, that's SIGTSTP, not SIGSTOP and it can be intercepted.

Comment: @sch, is that correct now?

Comment: Yes, though Ctrl-Z (and CTRL-C) causes a process _group_ (the foreground process group of the terminal) to receive that signal, not necessarily only one process. Also note SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU sent to processes not in the foreground process group of the terminal when then attempt to read or write from/to it, that also suspend them.

Comment: @sch: Isn't the process vs group only a difference in how the signal is sent?  IIRC `kill()` lets you send `SIGSTOP` to a group just fine.

Comment: Yes, my command was about your _CTRL-Z suspends the process..._ which may mislead people into thinking it is sent to just one process when it's actually a _job_ or _process group_.

Answer (score 19):

CTRL+Z stops (pauses) a job

CTRL+C terminates a job

with CTRL+C you cannot resume the process but with CTRL+Z the job can be resumed by just entering at the command promt:

```
fg %1
```

if you have multiple processes paused then you should do

```
jobs
```

to see the output and select the appropriate number to resume e.g.

```
fg %3
```

resumes the third job in the list. You can also have jobs running in the background with

```
bg %n
```

where n is the job number.

Comment: That's jobs (process groups), not processes that CTRL-C, CTRL-Z, fg and bg deal with.

Answer (score 4):

```
Cntrl + Z pause the currently running process.
```

And

```
Cntrl + C simply terminates the running process.
```

***Using Cntrl + C you can not resume the process. where as using Cntrl + Z you can resume the process.***

use fg %1 to resume the process.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> stops (pauses) a job

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminates a job

With <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you cannot resume the process, but with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the job can be resumed by just entering at the command prompt:

> fg %1

If you have multiple processes paused then you should do

> jobs

to see the output.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are correct, but for some unknown reason Ctrl-Z suspends all child processes as well, but killall -SIGSTOP ... only suspends the frontmost (parent) process and leaves the children to run as they like.