# How to shut down http-server on Ubuntu to make port free again?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a HTTP server that I startup using the following command

```
username@machine:~project/www$ http-server . --cors
```

It typically starts on port 8080, but if enter `ctrl+z` and then try to run the same command again, it will start on port 8081.

How can I shut down the previous server so that 8080 becomes free again?

Comment: Check if there if a shut-down option by running `http-server --help`, but after `Ctrl-Z` you will need to use `bg` to take it out of suspended state so that it can process a shut-down request. If programmatic shut-down is available, this is preferable to killing it, as it will do some tidying up before it exits. I don't have this server installed, so I can't check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the first background process you've created you can simply use `kill %1`. If not you'll want to run `jobs` and check which number it has in that list.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ctrl+c` to kill the process. `ctrl+z` just suspends it.

Further reading: [What's different between Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+C in Unix command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line)